# How to remove React hook in certain conditions?

Tags: reactjs, event-listener, react-hooks

Can't find a way to remove a hook when going to the next page section.

I've created a "useMousePosition" hook that tracks mouse position and returns mouse coordinates winch I use to transform some `<div/>`'s position. When scrolling down the page there's no need to transform the `<div/>` so I want to remove this useMousePosition hook.

**useMouseHook**

```
function useMousePosition() {
  let [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
    x: null,
    y: null
  });


function handleMouseMove(e) {
  setMousePosition({
    x: e.pageX,
     y: e.pageY
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, []);

  return mousePosition;
}
```

**Use hook in a component like so**

```
let { x, y } = useMousePosition();
```

I need to remove a hook when user has scrolled to the next page section (Component with hook doesn't unmount)

Comment: What does it mean "remove" hook? You want it to stop rendering?

Comment: or stop listening to the mouse move?

Comment: In this particular case I want to stop returning values, so, yes, to stop listening for an event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understood the question is that, you want to stop tracking the mouse movement.

If my understanding is correct, you can pass a flag to start/top tracking the mouse movement.

This demo shows that you can turn on/off the mouse tracking and

*You can follow along* 
[image: Edit so.answer.56777009]

[image: demo]

You can simply pass a variable, which you can check within your `useEffect`.

```
function useMousePosition(shouldTrack = true) {
  let [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
    x: null,
    y: null
  });

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
    setMousePosition({
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!shouldTrack) return;

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [shouldTrack]);

  return mousePosition;
}

function App() {
  const [useMouse, setUseMouse] = useState(true);
  let { x, y } = useMousePosition(useMouse);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`x, y`, x, y);
  }, [x, y]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setUseMouse(_ => !_)}>
        Tracking Mouse Movement is {useMouse ? "On" : "Off"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Clicking on the button toggles the track status.

And for "removing the hook", you can't as it's embedded in your Function Component.
You can at least prevent the "side effect" from running using a condition.

⚠ Note that `useEffect` has a dependency as `[shouldTrack]`.

Comment: I was trying to find the way to cancel hook influence on a component (like stop tracking mouse movement). I thought there would be some method to "turn off" a hook of some sort. This answer provides what I need. But you'd there's something "smarter" than an "if" statement

Comment: There isn't a smarter way  as it's not valid to run `useEffect` with `if` outside (only inside) according to [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify conditions in `handleMouseMove`

In the next solution, you stop render outside the pink border and remove the listener under the black line.

> Note: added `useCallback` and `dep array` because of unnecessary renderings.

[image]

```js
const isInsideBox = ({ pageX, pageY }) =>
  LEFT <= pageX && pageX <= RIGHT && TOP <= pageY;

function useMousePosition() {
  let [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
    x: null,
    y: null
  });

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    e => {
      isInsideBox(e) &&                     // Add Condition for Border
        setMousePosition({
          x: e.pageX,
          y: e.pageY
        });

      e.pageY >= BOTTOM &&                  // Add Condition for Black Line
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    },
    [setMousePosition]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [handleMouseMove]);

  return mousePosition;
}
```